# How to detect browser with AMPScript in ExactTarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, html, ssjs

I want to keep 2 URLs to one CTA which will navigate to the AppStore or Play Store depends the platform.

Is it possible by using AMPScript/Server-side JavaScript in ExactTarget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMPScript and SSJS are both evaluated server-side, so there's no chance to use either for detecting one device over the other.  And generally speaking, client-side scripting isn't allowed in email at all.

The two options I've seen:

1. Display both iOS and Android store CTAs in your email
2. Have a single CTA that takes the user to another web page that'll detect one or the other.

I'd have to say #1 is the most common.

Comment: There is also the opportunity to use 'real-time' content (e.g. LiveClicker) which can do as you ask. But this is a paid 3rd-party service. With the correct knowledge/time/money you can build your own, but for general needs it likely would not be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this by building a lightweight web application. The User-Agent request header will determine (by the web application) which image will returned. There are many libraries such as [device-detector](https://github.com/piwik/device-detector) and others that could achieve this.